# Access shared folder in local machine from EC2 instance

Tags: file-sharing, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2019

My company uses a windows server machine with some shared folders with files accessed by many pieces of code. Now I'll need to use several of those code files in an AWS EC2 machine that also runs windows Server. Is it possible to do so? It would be a nightmare to adapt all those code pieces to use some form of FTP, so if I could just enable the access, that would be a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

A few ways you could approach this. Ultimately, the Local server and the EC2 instance need to be able to talk to each other first and specifically, through SMB.

1. Use AWS Site-to-Site VPN and configure that with your companies on prem router to make the VPC and your local network all one big environment.
2. Configure OpenVPN so you can have your local machine able to talk with the VPC.
3. Port the local machines SMB port out of the firewall and use its public IP/port to map it from EC2.
4. Use a free service like Zerotier to create a virtual network where the 2 servers can talk.

If you have an IT department, the first option is the best for issues like this moving forward. It will establish the VPC in AWS as an extension of your local network at the company. If you are looking for the quickest method, it would be number 4 and you can install the zerotier clients on both machines and then they can mount the file share in only a few minutes.